# Is there an official nuget package for Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, npm, angular, nuget

I'm currently working in a work environment where I do not have access to npm / node. The npm download location is actually blocked so I can't get any packages.

I want to build an Angular 2 site. As I can't access npm, I want to use Nuget to get the files. Although I can see the Angular 1 packages, I cannot seem to see any Angular 2 packages. Is there one for Nuget?

Also, is populating the node_module folder and compiling the Typescript the only thing that npm does for Angular? If I can just get a copy of the node_module folder (from outside work) and get TypeScript working in my solution, can I basically bypass the need for npm?

Comment: Nuget is now discouraged source for JS packages. You could try to get it from some CDN https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/

Comment: @MichalDymel : I guess I'm just asking cause nearly every example on the net assumes I have npm, but I don't, so I'd like to know what exactly npm does for Angular. If it's just grabbing JS files, then yeah, I can just grab  from the CDNs but is that all I need npm for when working with angular2?

Comment: Yes, it's just grabbing files and putting them into node_modules folder.

Comment: I read here: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Angular-2-not-available-in-Bower that Angular 2 is compiled using Typescript, so it will still need to be pulled in via NuGet, though it is still not available in there.

Comment: @Neurothustra can you expand on that? I dont think that is correct

Comment: I was just wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In short; No.

You can see a list of all available NuGet package versions [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/angularjs/), with the most recent being 1.5.3.

Even performing a generic [search](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=angularjs) shows most recent versions as 1.5.3.

Sometimes they'll have beta versions of packages available that you can install with a command similar to: `Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.3-beta1 -Pre`, but it doesn't appear as if they have created any pre-release packages.

So, as @Michal Dymel mentioned, you could get it from a [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/) or some other location.